# How do you take a picture in Google App Maker?

Tags: android, image, google-app-maker

I'm new to App Maker, I can see and add images no problem but can't see a way to add images via camera in App Maker?

Comment: I think you can find the answers here.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use Drive Picker widget with upload enabled:

[image: Drive Picker config]
[image: Camera selection]